# Can I disable the default behaviour `hg add` with no arguments?

Tags: mercurial

When I run `hg add` with no arguments, it is *always* by mistake, and the result, adding all of the files and directories recursively, is horribly annoying and difficult to undo, especially when other files have been (correctly) added since the last commit. Is there any way to make a plain `hg add` just print an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting this in your `~/.hgrc`:

```
[defaults]
add = -X .
```

That tells `hg add` that unless specifically named it should ignore all files (got matches all).  Here's an example:

```
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:~ ry4an$ hg init test
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:~ ry4an$ cd test/
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ vi ~/.hgrc # added the section above
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ hg status
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ echo this > that
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ hg add  # nothing added
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ hg status
? that
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ hg add that
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:test ry4an$ hg status
A that
```

In general though, you should just make your `.hgignore` robust enough to ignore all the files you don't want added

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much exactly what I want. There's no error message but I don't really need that.

Answer (score 2):

In your user config file (`~/.hgrc`), add the following to your `[alias]` section:

```
[alias]
realadd = add
add = add --dry-run
```

Now, just `hg add` will always do a dry-run. To *actually* add, you have to use `hg realadd`. Note that you could redefine the `add` alias to do anything, it doesn't have to be `add --dry-run`.

Comment: That's kind of interesting but when I type `hg add` by mistake, it's because I mean to type, say `hg add %` from vim, and I somehow miss the percent sign and press enter. So if I do this, I'll still have the same problem, I'll just be typing `hg realadd`. If that makes sense?

Comment: There is no way you can get the computer to understand that you're doing something you didn't mean to do. What if you forced (if you could) it to require a parameter, but you hit enter too soon? At some point you're going to have to accept that if you make a mistake, the computer will not understand that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a way to do this purely with Mercurial configuration, but if you're willing to tune your bash profile, then you can redefine the `hg` command as a function.  The function would either detect `hg add` and fail or otherwise do a passthrough to the real `hg` command.

```
function hg() {
    if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "add" ]; then
        echo "hg add with no arguments denied" 1>&2
        false # sets exit code to 1, but doesn't close process like exit would
    else
        command hg $@
    fi
}
```

Here is what it looks like in action after I source in the new function from my profile:

```
hg > /dev/null; echo $?
0

hg add > /dev/null; echo $?
hg add with no arguments denied
1

hg add . > /dev/null; echo $?
0

hg status

touch afile

hg add afile

hg status
A afile
```

Comment: Just tried this.. the "hg add with no arguments denied" works, but if I do `hg add afile`, there's no error message but the file isn't actually added.

Comment: @AndrewMagee, I'm not sure why that wouldn't be working.  I just re-tested in my environment, and it worked.  I edited the usage example to show a working hg add and an hg status afterwards showing the file added.

Comment: Oh, actually you are right. Just tried it again and it does work. Not sure what was going on before.

Answer (score 1):

You can undo a global add using the following command:

```
hg forget $(hg status -an)
```

Here, `hg status -an` will list all added files. `hg forget` will then remove those files from the list of added files.

You can also create an alias for this in your `.hgrc`, e.g.:

```
[alias]
unadd = !$HG forget $($HG status -an)
```

Note that this will also delist all previously added files that you did mean to add, so you may have to redo that.

Also, operating systems and shells have limits for how many arguments can be passed to a command. If you run into this limit because you accidentally added more than a few thousand files, you can use `xargs` instead:

```
hg status -an | xargs hg forget
```

Or, as an alias:

```
[alias]
unadd = !$HG status -an | xargs $HG forget
```